# How do I modify my current binary search tree to be able to create an empty tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so far my code for creating a binary search tree is fine for what I'm trying to accomplish. However I would like for the `new` function to create an empty tree but my whole code as far as I can understand is based on a root value called when instancing a new object. How would I go about changing the code for `new` to return an empty BST instead of a tree with *one* root value as base? A relevant issue is also that the `size` attribute needs to start at 1 and I would like for it to start at 0. Thank you in advance.

Below is all the code linked.

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self._root = root
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._size = 1

    def add(self, root):
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree(root)
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._left.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree(root)
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._right.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
        else:
            self._root = root

    def string(self):
        if self._left:
            self._left.string()
        print(self._root),
        if self._right:
            self._right.string()

    def len(self):
        return self._size



def new(root):
    return BinaryTree(root)
```

Comment: Start with `_root` as None (rather than taking it as a parameter), and `_size` as 0.  Add 1 to `_size` after `self._root = root`.  You would also need to modify `string()` to print nothing if `_root` is None.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you for your answer. Your fix seems to be working aside from ```string``` part as you mentioned. If I, for instance try to add five strings a through c; 'a',...,'e', to a new object the ```string``` method only prints: a c e  and skips b and d.

Comment: Now that your trees are initially created empty, you need to explicitly add the first value when you create `_left` or `_right`.

Comment: @jasonharper how do I go about implementing what you suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mark added/changed lines with `# changed` comment:

```py
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, root=None):  # changed
        self._root = root
        self._left = None
        self._right = None
        self._size = 1 if root is not None else 0  # changed

    def add(self, root):
        if self._root:
            if root < self._root:
                if self._left is None:
                    self._left = BinaryTree(root)
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._left.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
            elif root > self._root:
                if self._right is None:
                    self._right = BinaryTree(root)
                    self._size += 1
                else:
                    self._right.add(root)
                    self._size += 1
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._size = 1  # changed

    def string(self):
        if self._left:
            self._left.string()
        print(self._root)  # changed, removed ","
        if self._right:
            self._right.string()

    def len(self):
        return self._size


def new(root=None):
    return BinaryTree(root)
```

Check also magic methods `__str__` and `__len__` they could help. Method `add` migth returns `self` which allow to add elements one by one in chain like that `add(1).add(10).add(100)`.